# how to open HTML page of subdirectory on URL hit

Tags: java, html, web.xml, subdirectory

i have a question:

I have a scenario that when user opens http://MYWEBSITE.com/abc/ , the user is directed to xyz.html page which is in abc subdirectory. I am using Java for web development. How can I do this in web.xml?

P.S. URL is http://MYWEBSITE.com/abc/ not http://MYWEBSITE.com/abc

Answer (score 0):

you can use the welcome-file attribute in the web.xml

example:

`<welcome-file>xyz.html</welcome-file>`

This would get tomcat to look for a page matching the name (if found) and load it.

Comment: actually welcome page is another page, and i want to open a different page when the URL is HIT.

Comment: you can have multiple entries... tomcat looks for these files in the order it has been mentioned ...